# Does Linux log when a process is started, and the PID that gets assigned to it? Where can I find that log?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

When my Ubuntu server starts up, I see a message that says: `kernel: [11.895392] init: failsafe main process (631) killed by TERM signal`. I would like to know what process this is but I'm not sure where to look.  When I search through my `syslog` and `kernel.log`, I don't see any evidence of processes starting and being given an identifier (PID).

I'd like to investigate my boot message (failsafe main process killed...) but first, I need to answer the question: When a process starts, where is that logged and does the PID that is assigned to it get logged as well?

I understand that a process will write a PID file to reference later as necessary, but once the process is killed, can I find out what PID it used to have?

Comment: No, started processes are not logged. There are too many.

Comment: You can't find the PID of killed processes.

Comment: Only some processes have .pid files in /var/run.

Comment: Only daemons will have the PID files (because they need it).

Comment: @ciro you marked this as a duplicate?  I posted this question in 2012.  The one that is being linked to is from Oct 2014.  Interesting logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all your message already contains the program name:

```
kernel: [11.895392] init: failsafe main process (631) killed by TERM signal
```

This means that the program `failsafe` with the pid `631` received a `TERM` signal.

To answer your original question, no most Linux Distributions don't log the pids of created processes per default but you can use the [audit framework](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) and create the necessary rules to log all created processes. https://www.wzdftpd.net/docs/selinux/audit.html provides an introduction into these rules and should help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

You could log newly executed commands/processes using [Snoopy](https://github.com/a2o/snoopy).

If you need simple logger and you are NOT looking for security/auditing solution, then Snoopy might be it.

Disclosure: Snoopy maintainer here.